# How to track download speed in CRA?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I have a CRA and I'm trying to work out the download speed of the index.html. how can I see this? I can see the `.chunk.js` file took 11seconds to download over slow 3G and it's only 250kb~, is this normal?

I want to work out how quick the html takes to load so I can then work out how long the javascript takes to kick it and monitor this whole speed process. anyone have any good tips for doing this?

currently setting sessionStorage to be `Date.Now()` but need to know exactly when to fire this so I'm comparing 2 accurate values

Answer (score 0):

This solution won't be able to pin down the exact time taken to load index.html, but it assesses the website from a user's perspective and tells you what possible optimizations you can make. If your end goal is simply performance optimization, I recommend using [`lighthouse`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse).

The screenshot below shows the assessment results and time taken for certain items to load or be perceived as visible/interactable.

[image: lighthouse]
They're using the Chrome DevTools in this screenshot but there's also a [CLI version](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse#cli) (which I prefer more ).